# The NodeEntity caches the value of the Set

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

I'm using the Spring Data Neo4j 4. It seems the "PersistenceContext" of Neo4j cache the values of the "Set" value.

The Entity

```
@NodeEntity
public class ServiceStatus implements java.io.Serializable {

    @GraphId Long id;

    private Set<String> owners = new HashSet<String>();

}
```

First, I put a value "ROLE_ADMIN" in the owners and save it.
Then I edit the value to "ROLE_SYSTEM_OWNER" and called save() again.

In the Neo4j query browser, it only show the "ROLE_SYSTEM_OWNER", which is all correct for now.

However, when I called the findAll(), the owners has two values ["ROLE_ADMIN","ROLE_SYSTEM_OWNER"]

It will work fine when I restart my web server.

[The way to change value]

```
@Test
public void testSaveServiceStatus() throws OSPException {
    //1. save 
    ServiceStatus serviceStatus = new ServiceStatus();
    serviceStatus.setServiceName("My Name");

    Set<String> owners = new HashSet<String>();
    owners.add("ROLE_SITE_ADMIN");
    serviceStatus.setOwners(owners);

    serviceStatusRepository.save(serviceStatus);

    System.out.println(serviceStatus.getId()); //262

}

@Test
public void testEditServiceStatus() throws OSPException{
    //1. to find all , it seems cache the set value
    serviceStatusRepository.findAll();


    //2. simulate the web process behavior
    ServiceStatus serviceStatus = new ServiceStatus();
    serviceStatus.setId(new Long(262));
    serviceStatus.setServiceName("My Name");

    Set<String> owners = new HashSet<String>();
    //change the owner to Requestor
    owners.add("Requestor");
    serviceStatus.setOwners(owners); 

    //3. save the "changed" value 
    // In the cypher query browser, it show "Requestor" only
    serviceStatusRepository.save(serviceStatus);

    //4. retrieve it again
    serviceStatus = serviceStatusRepository.findOne(new Long(262));

    System.out.println(serviceStatus); //ServiceStatus[id=262,serviceName=My Name,owners=[Requestor5, Requestor4]]

}
```

Comment: How do you edit the value? Can you share the code because I'm unable to reproduce this. Which version of sdn 4 btw?

Comment: Add the Test method, 
Because it is web environment, it has to be in the same application lifecycle

1. get the entry first  (The value is cached)
2. create a new instance and change the owner from "ROLE_SITE_ADMIN" to "Requestor"
3. Get the entry again from repository to display in the browser.

Comment: Thanks, I think I did the same but I'll verify. Which version of sdn 4?

Comment: The version is  4.0.0.RC1

Answer (score 1):

Your test appears to be working with detached objects in a way. Step one, findAll() loads these entities into the session, but then step 2 instead of using the loaded entity, creates a new one which is subsequently saved. The "attached" entity still refers to the earlier version of the entity.
The OGM does not handle this currently.

You're best off modifying the entity loaded in findAll or just a findOne(id), modify, save (instead of recreating one by setting the id). That will ensure everything is consistent.

Comment: Thank oyu Luanne, The work around I'm using is to copy the properties with BeanUitls.